# Sockets with OSGi: Bundle stopped, socket still open

Tags: java, sockets, osgi

I'm facing this issue working with a `ServerSocket` inside one of my bundles, let's just call it: *FooBundle*.

This *FooBundle* has, among others, a `SocketListener.java` class. This class is a Thread and to make a little overview of it, I'll paste some pseudocode:

```
public class SocketListener implements Runnable{

ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection = null;
private boolean closeIt = false;

   public void run() {
        try {
            //Create the server socket
            providerSocket = new ServerSocket(41000, 10);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            //catching the exception....
        }
        while(!closeIt){
        try{
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(onnection.getInputStream()));
            while(in.hasNext() !=false) 
                    message = message + " "+in.next();
              // bla bla bla...
            } catch (IOException e) {
              //bla bla...
            }
        finally{
         try{
              if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
                  providerSocket.close();
                          closeIt = true;
             }
       catch(IOException ioException){
        //........
         }
}
```

As you can see, it's a simple thread that waits for a connection until the message it receives from one of the **SocketClients** is *"bye"*.

This is the problem I'm facing right now: When the Bundle is **stopped**, I do need to **restart** the entire *OSGi framework* : If I try to restart the bundle, a `java.net.BindException` message is thrown: "*Address already in use*". So, I stopped the bundle but the socket hasn't been closed.

In OSGi, you need to take care of what the `stop()` method inside the `Activator` must include, but I just can't pass any reference of an anonymous thread to the Activator.

Imagine that this is my class diagram inside the bundle:

```
**FooBundle**
|__FooBundleActivator
|__FooImpl
|__SocketListener (thread)
```

The `SocketListener` thread is called from the `FooImpl` class as an **anonymous thread**.

My question is: Is there any appropiate method to have such control of anonymous threads and specifically in my case, of non-closing socket ports, inside the OSGi paradigm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your bundle is told to stop then assume the guy doing the stopping knows what he is doing. Yes, your protocol expects the 'bye' but shit happens, any protocol that has problems with these things is too fragile for the real world. In general, all your tasks in OSGi should have a life cycle. So this would be my code (using DS instead of activators).

```
@Component
public class ProtocolServer extends Thread {
  volatile ServerSocket server;
  volatile Socket connection;

  public ProtocolServer() {
    super("Protocol Server on 4100"); // to identify the thread
  }

  @Activate void activate() {
    setDaemon(true);
    start();
  }

  @Deactivate void deactivate() {
     interrupt();

     // best effort close (even if null)
     try { server.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
     try { connection.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}

     join(10000); // waits 10 secs until thread exits
  }

  public void run() {
    // loop for active component
    while( !isInterrupted() )
    try {
      doServer();
    } catch( Exception e) {
      log(e);

      // bad error, accept failed or bind failed
      // or server socket was closed. If we should remain
      // active, sleep to prevent overloading the
      // system by trying too often, so sleep

      if ( !isInterrupted() )
         try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
  }

  private void doServer() throws Exception {
      server = new ServerSocket(4100)
      try {
         while( !isInterrupted() )
           doConnection(server);
      } finally {
        server.close();
      }
  }

  private void doConnection(ServerSocket server) throws Exception {
    connection = server.accept();
    try {
      doMessages(connection);

      // the pseudo code exits here, but that seems
      // kind of weird? If desired, interrupt
      // this object, this will exit the thread

    } catch( Exception e) {
       log(e); // the connection failed, is not uncommon
    } finally {
      connection.close();
      connection = null;
    }
  }

  private void doMessages(Socket connection) {
    MyScanner s = new MyScanner(socket);
    String msg;
    while( !isInterrupted() && !"bye".equals( msg=s.getMessage()))
      process(msg);
  }
}
```

One important design consideration in OSGi is that the components keep working even if there are failures. In a network you often have transient errors that go away on their own. Even if they don't it is desirable that the server keeps on trying while you fix the problem. Your pseudo code would be a nightmare in practice since it would disappear on any error. Any system with multiple such components tends to becomes quickly unstable.

One thing that also surprised me is that you only support one connection at a time. In general it is better to not limit this and handle the messages in their own thread. In that case, you must ensure that each created handler for a connection is also closed appropriately.

Comment: The issue about receiving just one client is because of the pseudocode, my real code accepts multiple connections. Thanks a lot for your answer Peter. Not only for the code, but also for the advices. It's really been an honor receiving an answer from Peter Kriens. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate the ServerSocket outside (probably in the Activator) and pass it to the SocketListener via a constructor. You can call serverSocket.stop() in the stop function of the Activator than.

In case you call ServerSocket.stop() a SocketException will be thrown that is a subclass of IOException. Please think of handling IOException in the while iteration in the way that it will stop executing the iteration for sure.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Balazs. The only issue I'm facing with your approach is that I already have "overloaded" the activator too much, so I wouldn't like any more code inside. The start and stop methods should be simple to avoid any delay in the activation of the bundle. Anyway, you gave me a good idea for future deployments. +1

Comment: Well, in this case you must separate somehow the start and stop logic to functions and classes. However if you create new classes they also have to have the stop/close functions. Anyway the only solution is for you to be able to stop the server socket when the bundle stops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close that listening socket regardless of the message before exiting the thread function. Then what should really make a difference for you is calling [`setReuseAddress(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) on that socket to allow binding the port while old connection hangs in the timeout state.

And, please please please, use better indentation technique in your code ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikolai. However, setting the ReuseAddress parameter as true doesn't really solve this issue, since I'm still getting the same Bind Exception. My thread needs to be alive until the message "bye" arrives, there can't be any other possible condition for this (it must run continuosly). The problem with OSGi bundles is that you can stop them manually at any moment. If this particular bundle is stopped, the socket doesn't close itself. Oh and sorry for indent, just wrote the pseudocode manually :S. +1 for help

Comment: You can't "re-bind" the same socket. You either have to close it and create a new one, or just stop calling `accept()` on it, and resume later.

Comment: The problem with this is that I cannot create a new one, since I have many clients forwarding to this particular port. The solution right now is to stop the entire OSGi framework, which is not really "good" for my application. There should be any kind of method to control what anonymous threads "make" inside a bundle, but I can't find the proper solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework. Do you have any "hooks"/callbacks from it on "start"/"stop" events? I would imagine you'd need to override some functions, where you'd be able to create/close your socket(s). Watch out, those might be on a different thread.

Comment: You're right, the socket doesn't close itself. Did you think OSGi would handle this for you, "for free"?? Anything you create in the start() method of your bundle must be cleaned up in the stop() method. That includes any sockets you open, any threads you start, etc. This is your responsibility as the author of the bundle, not anybody else's. If you need to restructure your code to make this possible, then so be it.